# C++ return a promise / future

Tags: c++, future

I am trying to turn some synchronous (winsock2) code into asynchronous code with [promises](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise).

```cpp
void sendRequest() {
    sendto(...);
    recvfrom(..., buffer);
    return buffer;
}
```

I believe [sendto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-sendto) & [recvfrom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recvfrom) are thread blocking. How would I go about returning a Promise / Future?

In Javascript I would go about it with:

```js
function sendRequest() {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        // get data
        res(myBuffer);
    });
}
```

Can and how would that translate to c++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
auto future = std::async(std::launch::async, sendRequest);
```

or

```
auto future = std::async(std::launch::async, []{ ... });
```

Would be what you're after.

But better switch to asynchronous sockets (with [asio](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) or whatever else). Asynchronous socket libraries, such as asio, may use platform-specific options to avoid blocking calls, so you don't need to do your operation in threadpool.

If you're using winsock, and have no plans migrating to other platforms, you can also use directly windows asynchronous sockets.